# Ubuntu 12.04 key bindings not working in IntelliJ Idea 12

Tags: intellij-idea, ubuntu-12.04, ubuntu-unity

I've installed the latest version of IntelliJ Idea Community Edition (12.0.1) and I have problems with key bindings there. I am using Ubuntu 12.04 LTS with Unity.

None of them, where a letter is involved (ctrl-a, ctrl-c, ctrl-v) are working in Idea. And they are working in all other applications.

I can copy/paste text in Idea with mouse and it shows me that key bindings for this are ctrl-c/ctrl-v, but they are just not working.

I have no idea what is the problem, so any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Usually such kind of problem is because of non-English keyboard layout being first in a list of layouts in OS settings. Try to reorder them.

Comment: Thanks, nasty one - of course propagated to Lubuntu, was almost ready to uninstall Intellij...

Answer (score 0):

I just experienced the same problem after installed 14.0.3. It seemed due to Tools > Vim Emulator was checked. The problem was resolved after uncheck it.